# Im trying to display latest post from my sharepoint discussion board to my main page?

Tags: sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have a community site with a discussion board and I would like to display a few of the latest posts on my main start-up page?

How would one go about it in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution allows to modify Discussion List web part properties that are not available from UI.

### Enable web part Export capabilities

In order to modify web part properties that are not available from UI, we need to enable Export capabilities:

- Add Discussions List on the page.
- Open the page in SharePoint Designer (SPD)
- Find the property [ExportControlledProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.exportcontrolledproperties.aspx) and set its value
  to `True` in order to enable web part Export capabilities
- Save the page in SPD

### Change web part properties

From now the export action have to be available as shown on picture below
[image]

Assume we need to display the 4 latest discussions.

Discussion default view (`Subject`) has the following properties:

```
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">20</RowLimit>
```

In order to change these properties follow the steps below:

- Export web part file
- Find the property [XmlDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.xmldefinition.aspx) and change `RowLimit` element
  `Paged` attribute to `FALSE` and value to `4`
- Upload and add web part on page

### Result

[image]

---

### How to display Discussions using CQWP

In order to aggregate Discussions from a different site you could utilize Content Query web part (CQWP).

Steps:

- add `Content Query` web part (located under `Content Roollup` category)
- go to web part settings and specify the  `Query`settings  as shown on picture below
  [image]
- and specify `Sorting` settings as shown on picture
  [image]

Comment: Thnx!
But pardon my 'Rookiness' but i followed all the steps and i can only use the exported web-part on the same site not on different sites as requested. I want to use it on my start page how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a List Style I found that made the CQWP work properly.

```
<xsl:template name="DiscussionStyle" match="Row [@Style='DiscussionStyle']" mode="itemstyle">
  <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
   <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
    <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:variable>
 <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td class="S2StyleTitle" colspan="2">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
    <a href="{@LinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}" style="font-size:11px;">
     <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
    </a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="S2StyleBorder">
   <td class="S2StyleDescription" valign="top">
    <span style="color:#808080"><strong>Posted</strong>:
     <xsl:value-of select="@PubDate"/>
    </span>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</xsl:template>
```

[How to Configure a Custom Item Style for a Discussion Board using the Content Query Web Part](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/04/18/how-to-configure-a-custom-item-style-for-a-discussion-board-using-the-content-query-web-part-aspx/)